# Do you use Scimore SQL database?

Tags: sql, firebird, scimore

There's a database engine that looks amazing for a free tool and that is [Scimore](http://www.scimore.com/).

Have you had much experience with it?  If so, how does it rate..particularly against Firebird?  How resilient/self reliant is it? (Meaning how much downtime/maintenance is expected?) The scale out capabilities also look very interesting.

I just downloaded it and have been playing around and so far it looks good.  I had been looking for an easy to deploy single-user type embedded database (which Scimore has an option) and was toying with MS SQL Compact Edition and SQLite and remembered this database from a trial a few years ago.   (Windows platform)

I was about ready to settle in on SQLite but started thinking about other projects which are multi-user and wanted to stick with a single solution...which is why I started looking at Firebird as well.

Comment: I'm interested to know if you actually choose Scimore and if so, what are you experiences so far?

Comment: I did not end up sticking with Scimore.  It seemed fast and stable but I went with more established options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not expect downtime with Scimore. It has all the bells and whistles that you will find in expensive database products, MVCC, ACID transactions, tolerance to your application crashing etc.

From what we hear, the primary reason to switch to Scimore Embedded, is robustness when having high concurrency, large datasets and large load.

An intersting thing that differentiates Scimore from other databases is that it grows from:

- embedded inside your application processes. We know of applications based on ScimoreDB Embedded with more than 1.5 mio installations.
- embedded with your application, but running in a seperate processes outside your application. It allows for multiple applications to share & modify data.
- runs as a "standard" windows service, similar to a mysql/sql server/oracle
- it runs distributed over many machines. You install the distributed instance (service) on many machines, join them into a cluster. You can now connect to any instance
  and it will orchestrate your SQL queries over the machines in the cluster. Longest running cluster of 5 machines has been running for more than 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

[FAQ](http://www.scimore.com/support/faq.aspx) is a quite nice start

**Can I get access to the source code?**
[ScimoreDB]Yes, sign a support contract.

Firebird is Open source

**Do you support integration with developer studio?**
[ScimoreDB]No. We are working on both Linq and DDEX functionality. There is yet no release date

Firebird have.

**Linux – do you have a linux version?**
[ScimoreDB]Almost. Using Wine, we almost got there, but unfortunately the library seems to have some bugs for async socket and disc access.

Firebird have